# Service account application

Tags: google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-meet

I would like to make service account application in C# that every x minutes/hours check for all the users in the organization drive for downloading google meet recordings.(Is that even possible?)

I've already created a project in the developer console with service account that has domain-wide authority.

I just need the the following steps :

1. Authenticating - Should I do it every time my app runs or I can save the access token generated in the data base and use it and only when expires to regenerate ?
   2)Most important - after having token how should I check for all my org users for new recordings in drive ?

Thanks!

I need the ability to check on all my org users drive files for download meeting recordings.

Comment: With service accounts just let it authorize everything you run it.  The library should handle everything for you.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for reply.
As I go to understand I need to register ServiceAccountCredential  . This is done as follows  

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusMe }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

How do I get the certificate?

Comment: I would think you would want to use a googe drive scope not a google plus scope

Comment: Yes sure I did it.
The problem now that the list of files is empty

Comment: well if the service account doesnt have any files its not going to be able to list them.  If you want to access files of users on your domain then you need to delegate the service count to a user on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

To access a users data on the workspace domain you need to add the CreateWithUser and add the email address of the user on your domain you want the service account to impersonate. This will give you access to the files on their google drive account.

```
private static GoogleCredential LoadGoogleCredentails()
    {
        return GoogleCredential.FromFile(PathToServiceAccountKeyFile)
            .CreateScoped(Scopes)
            .CreateWithUser(workspaceAdmin);
    }
```

Note PathToServiceAccountKeyFile is the JSON key file not the p12 file you are using.

Comment: Thank you very much so far ,
But what if I want to check on all my organization users ?
Should I loop through each user with the function you mentioned ?

Comment: Yup loop though them changing the CreateWithUser each time.